How to query AWS list-objects-v2 to return a result set of Glacier Deep Archive objects which have been restored
I'm trying to find a good way to list items within a bucket prefix that have been transitioned from Glacier Deep Archive to Standard. I see there is a RestoreStatus->IsRestoreInProgress (boolean). According to the docs the key only exists for items that have been restored, and the value will be false for items which have been restored. So I am trying to limit my results to that with:
aws s3api list-objects --bucket $BUCKET --prefix $PREFIX --query "Contents[?contains(IsRestoreInProgress, `false`)]"

That doesn't return any results, but there should be many files that fit that criteria, I am able to see the restore status using head-object for a single file at a time, but it would be much better if I could use the list-objects-v2 --query filter to only return those items under a given prefix
